# MS Word: Insert a page of a field selection in

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

I would like to know if there is a way to insert text or a page based off field selection in Microsoft Word? 
I am working on a template that when opens:
1.  Prompts for name of project, and parts used,
2.  Then fills in fields in the page where the project name and information need to go, and finally,
3.  based off what was typed for parts used, will add a page or text that talks about proper procedures of that part.

I open the template, and get a prompt asking for project name, I put t101, then I get a prompt asking for part, I put manhole, after clicking okay. the top reads "PROJECT: t101" and pages are added below that explain how to install a manhole.
 I already have the prompt and filling in the fields part done. I am unfamiliar of a way to insert pages in this way. Is this possible? Any advice or direction in how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your version of Word? Are you using VBA or strictly Field automation?

Comment: Word 2016, no vba as of yet although I am not opposed to it, so far everything is done with field automation.

Answer (score 0):

To add a page worth of text automatically use the "IF" function pasting the full text of the needed page in the last set of quotation marks, mine looked like this:

```
{ If "myfield"="Manhole" "MANHOLE DATA SHEET ..."}
```